# psql import .csv - Double Quoted fields and Single Double Quote Values

Tags: postgresql, csv, psql

Hello Stack Overflowers,

Weird question. I am having trouble importing a .csv file using psql command line arguments...

The .csv is comma delimited and there are double quotes around cells/fields that have commas in them. I run into an issue where one of the cells/fields has a single double-quote that is being used for inches. So in the example below, it thinks the bottom two rows are all one cell/field.

I can't seem to find a way to make this import correctly. I am hoping to not have to make changes to the file itself and just adjust my psql command.

```
Ex:
number, number, description  (Headers)
123,124,"description, description"
123,124,description, TV 55"
123,124,description, TV 50"

Command Ex:
\copy table FROM 'C:\Users\Desktop\folder\file.csv' CSV HEADER
\copy table FROM 'C:\Users\Desktop\folder\file.csv' WITH CSV HEADER QUOTE '"' ESCAPE '\'
```

I've noticed saving using excel fixes the issue... Excel formats the records like...

```
number, number, description  (Headers)
123,124,"description, description"
123,124,"description, TV 55"""
123,124,"description, TV 50"""
```

I don't want to save using excel though because I have numbers that are turned into scientific notation and leading zeros are dropped immediately upon opening the file in excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an ugly hack, but you can import into a single-column table with `\copy table from '/path/to/file' CSV quote e'\x01' delimiter e'\x02'` and then try to fix it in SQL with regex functions. This is only workable with reasonably small CSVs since you're duplicating the data in the single-column table while doing the import.

```
testdb=# create table import_data(t text);
CREATE TABLE
testdb=# \! cat /tmp/oof.csv
num0,num1,descrip
123,124,"description, description"
123,124,description, TV 55"
123,124,"description, TV 50""
testdb=# \copy import_data from /tmp/oof.csv csv header quote e'\x01' delimiter e'\x02'
COPY 3
testdb=# CREATE TABLE fixed AS
SELECT
  (regexp_split_to_array(t, ','))[1] num1,
  (regexp_split_to_array(t, ','))[2] num2,
  regexp_replace(
        regexp_replace(regexp_replace(t, '([^,]+,[^,]+),(.*)', '\2'),
                       '"(.*?)"', '\1'),
        '(.*)(")?', '\1\2') as descrip
FROM import_data;
SELECT 3
testdb=# select * from fixed;
 num1 | num2 |         descrip          
------+------+--------------------------
 123  | 124  | description, description
 123  | 124  | description, TV 55"
 123  | 124  | description, TV 50"
(3 rows)
```

Comment: It's a rough go lol. I think I'll give your suggestion a go though. I just literally can't think of anything else. Ideally, the original data delimiter can be changed to a pipe but not sure if it will be possible.